# how can i get words out of pdf file in android

Tags: java, android, pdf

i am new to android programing.
I am trying to build a small app that uses the words of pdf file.
Is there any way to get them? 
maybe a library that works with pdf format?

Comment: dup? "What is the best PDF open source library for Java? " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a good quality commercial solution, take a look at [Aspose.Pdf for Android](http://www.aspose.com/android/pdf-component.aspx). It is a PDF processing library that enables you to create, manipulate and edit documents. Features include:

> PDF compression options, support for graph objects, extensive hyperlink functionality, extended security controls, custom font handling, integration with data sources, adding or removing bookmarks, working with attachments and annotations, importing or exporting PDF form data, working with text and images, splitting, concatenating, extracting or inserting pages, converting pages to images and much more.

Here is a simple example to extract text from a PDF file.

```
String input = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Document1.pdf").toString();
// Load the PDF document
Document doc = new Document(input);
// Create a text absorber
TextAbsorber absorber = TextAbsorber();
// Accept page 1 for absorber.
doc.getPages().get_Item(1).accept(absorber);
// Extract all text from page 1
String text = absorber.getText();
Log.i("PDF", text);
```

PS: I am a developer at Aspose.

Answer (score 1):

PDF reading/writing is a huge problem that many Android developers face and sadly, there are very few open source resources available. Most libraries that would work on the JVM use swing and other libraries which are not compatible with Android's VM.

[MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/) and [PlugPDF](http://plugpdf.com/) will work if you are allowing the user to read the pdf and select the text they want to extract from it. Both are free including PlugPDF which is free if you are an indie developer.

If you are willing to pay money, there are many commercial libraries which are capable of extracting text from a pdf (iText and Aspose come to mind).